# Does docker auto delete files inside /tmp directory?

Tags: docker

I have a nodejs application with docker and application has added some files in /tmp folder inside docker container.
now after 3-4 days that file from /tmp folder is missing.
so does doker auto removes files from /tmp folder ??

Comment: Docker is just hosting your system, but I imagine image it is running is cleaning the folder. After all it is temp folder. You should check the behaviour of your Docker image's OS

Comment: Docker does not automatically delete files.  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?  Are you mounting something on `/tmp`, and some other process is cleaning it up?  Or does your application log to files in that directory, and there's log rotation in your logging layer?